# Django file upload failure

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm quiet new to django.I have met a problem when I tryied to write a page handling the uploading files.Here are the codes:

## models.py:

```
   class HomeworkContent(models.Model):
        homework = models.ForeignKey(Homework, related_name="content_homework")
        student = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="content_student")
        grade = models.IntegerField(blank = True, default = -1)
        description = models.CharField(blank = True, max_length = 1000)
        file = models.FileField(upload_to='file/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True,null=True)
```

## view.py:

```
@login_required
def submit_homework(request, course_id, assignment_id):
    user  = request.user
    form = HomeworkContentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            content = HomeworkContent()
            content.file = request.FILES['file']
            content.description = form.cleaned_data["description"]
            content.save()
            return render_to_response('assignment_detail.html', locals(),  RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = HomeworkContentForm()
    return render_to_response('assignment_submit.html',locals(), RequestContext(request))
```

## html:

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <table>
    <tr><th><label for="id_description">description:</label></th><td><input id="id_description" maxlength="1000"          name="description" type="text" /></td></tr>
    <tr><th><label for="id_file">File:</label></th><td><input id="id_file" name="file" type="file" /></td></tr>
   </table>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />

  </form>
```

## forms.py

```
class HomeworkContentForm(forms.Form):
    description = forms.CharField(label = u'description', required = False, max_length = 1000)
    file = forms.FileField()
```

So what is the problem? I would appreciate it very much if someone could help me.

Comment: Any hint about the problem? Could be anything :P

Comment: the problem is that nothing happens when I submit the file.So I'm quiet confused

Comment: For instance it seems you're not including `User` and `Homework` which are necessaries when you save the `HomeworkContent`

Comment: Post the form definition please. Nothing happens because most likely the form is not validating I guess.

Comment: I have tried include User and Homework, it still apears to be the same.

Comment: How did you tried that?

Comment: just add 'user' and 'homework' attributes to the dic content, is that ok?

Comment: What's the dic content? Also do some testing? Add an `else` clause to the `if form.is_valid()` and `raise Exception(form.errors)` to see if the form has some errors.

Comment: I mean content. Let me have a try

Comment: Oops,I find what's wrong with it.I just made a mistake in the url.py and it didn't call the right function. Thanks very much!